# Background-image для svg масштабироваться до div?

Tags: css, svg

background-size не работает, svg выводится обрезанным, урезанным как угодно но не подстраивается под блок родительский.

Он должен масштабироваться до его размеров, как происходит с растровым изображением.
Из-за чего это и как это исправить?

Вот код html и css:

```
 <div class="wrapperSvgImage"></div>

.wrapperSvgImage {
    background-image: url(images/logo.svg);
    background-size: contain;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
.wrapperSvgImage {
    background-image: url(images/logo.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не помешал бы кусок кода. `background-size: contain;` не работает?

Comment: Добавил пример кода и как выглядит.
И вообще svg выводится только на реальном домене, на локальном 192.168.1.50 не выводит вообще svg. Пустой блок.

Comment: А разве высоту и ширину не нужно конкретно задавать? Тогда `contain` должен сработать. Вот почитайте https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: А без указания пикселей нельзя сделать? 
Как узнать размер svg в пикселях? Например скачиваю с инета картинку как узнать её размер чтобы правильно указать в css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По делу: блок с картинкой должен быть пропорциональным картинке если хотите чтобы не растягивалась она. Если не знаете размеров картинки открывайте *firebug* и меняйте ширину/высоту пока не подойдет.

```
.wrapperSvgImage {
  background-image: url(http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 82px;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Вот вам пример. Можете еще задать разрешение `backgroud-size` в пропорциях к оригинальной картинке но лучше все таки использовать `cover`.  https://jsfiddle.net/0cs7w123/2/ - вот пример с небезызвестным киви.

Comment: Я не понимаю, если родительский блок указан в процентах, то получается svg не способен растянутся(хотя бы в 1 направлении)?
То есть резиновый дизайн с svg не получиться сделать?

Comment: Можно играться с родительским элементом а элемент с картинкой задавать в процентах. Но все равно нужно пропорциональный изображению блок. Но могу ошибаться, по крайней мере у меня не было проблем с использованием конкретных величин к svg. Это же логотип к примеру. Вот пример с родительским. https://jsfiddle.net/0cs7w123/3/